# Despite my php/mysql code looking fine, a recordset isn't showing up in my page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query and want to output the code.  This is the only query that isn't working as it should.

All the other queries I have on that page work fine.  When I run the query in phpmyadmin, the information shows up.  It's just when I bring it into the PHP for some reason, this ONE query fails.

The query and setting the 2 variables :

```
$rsEnc = new WA_MySQLi_RS("rsEnc",$ecmNew,1);
$rsEnc->setQuery("SELECT * FROM encans ORDER BY encanid DESC");
$rsEnc->execute();

$enctitle = $rsEnc->getColumnVal("encname");
$encabout = $rsEnc->getColumnVal("encdesc");
```

and then further down :

```
<div>ABOUT: <?=$encabout?></div>
```

Nothing shows up here.  When I run that same query in phpmyadmin, I get the expected data.  So why wouldn't this do the obvious?  Am I looking past some glaring bug here?

Comment: Knowing what exactly the error message from the query is would help.

Comment: There is no error at all.  There is just no output.

Comment: I would love to give you more info but that's pretty much it.  I even checked if somehow I had some css reason but the data isn't even showing up in the source code.

Comment: Why `getColumnVal` as opposed to looking at results `foreach($rsEnc->Results[0] as $key => $val) { ...`?

Comment: I'm had originally made this using WebAssist's DreamWeaver mysqli extension. The code for this is :

``` public function getColumnVal($col) {
   $colVal = "";
   if (isset($this->Results[$this->Index]) && isset($this->Results[$this->Index][$col])) $colVal = $this->Results[$this->Index][$col];
   return $colVal;
 }
```

Comment: All the queries use this and they always work... until this one query.

Comment: OK.. I am a bit pressed for time and I found a workaround so I'm going to use it.  I managed to combine this query with another one and got the data to show up.  Not sure why this happened but if anyone can figure it out, then great..otherwise, let's drop this!  Thanks for your time, danblack!